# addEventListener not working for a HTML Button that is within a Django for loop

Tags: javascript, django-templates, addeventlistener, queryselector

I am trying to call a function when an HTML button is clicked, but right now, a `console.log` is supposed to run when the button is clicked, but nothing appears in the console. This button is within a for loop in Django and is being selected via `querySelector` through its class. I want only the specific button that is clicked to be selected, but I do not know if anything is being selected because nothing happens when the button is clicked.

javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('.edit_button').addEventListener('click', () => console.log("test"));
});
```

html

```
{% for post in page_obj.object_list %}
            <div class = "individual_posts">
                <h6 id = "post_itself">{{ post.post }}</h6>
                {% if post.user == request.user %}
                    <button id="editButton" class="edit_button">Edit</button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelector` only returns the first element that matches the query.
Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements that are matches. Loop over result and add the event listeners per button.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit_button');
  for (const button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("test"));
  }
});
```

Comment: I changed my code to yours, but still nothing is happening in the console.

Comment: That could mean a couple of things: (1 The script is not loading. (2 There is an error elsewhere causing the script to fail. (3 Your HTML is different and no buttons with the `.edit_button` class is found. Please check these options.